# PHP http_build_query with numbers in string

Tags: php

I am trying to build a query string with http_build_query, and it is producing unexpected results when a number is passed as one of the values in the array.

```
$number = '123';
$data   = array(
    'first'     => $number,
    'second'    => 'test',
);
http_build_query( $data );
//output is first%123&second=test
//unexpected output is % after first instead of =

$number = '500';
$data   = array(
    'first'     => $number,
    'second'    => 'test',
);
http_build_query( $data );
//output is firstP0&second=test
//unexpected output is P0 after first instead of =500

$number = '1';
$data   = array(
    'first'     => $number,
    'second'    => 'test',
);
http_build_query( $data );
//output is first=1&second=test
//output has an equal sign and not a percent sign
```

In the first example, there is a percent sign in the place where I would expect there to be an equal sign.

The second example changes =500 to P0.

The third example is what I'd expect all the time, but for some reason, it seems like the length of the number is changing the output between a `%` and `=`

Note: I tried this with various length numbers (1, 12, 1234, 12345, etc.), and with different numbers. Only the single digit example (regardless of whether I use 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) is able to produce the equal sign like expected.

Is there a way to pass numbers to `http_build_query()` where it will not have an unexpected output like I referenced in the examples?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I ran your shared code in CLI PHP 5.6.2, as well as on http://phpfiddle.org and got correct output (it did not look like what you say you're getting)

Comment: I don't know why this is happening. I can not reproduce it using my local php server (7.1.4) the output returns as expected (`first=123&second=test, first=500&second=test, first=1&second=test`)

Comment: Have you tried putting the number in the array directly instead of via a variable?

Comment: After these responses, I'm wondering if it's a quirk with the version of PHP that I'm running (5.5.24) or perhaps the localhost server I'm running it on. I'm going to look into running it on another server to see if it works there.

Comment: And @sorayadragon, yes I even tried building the query string manually, but the output on the screen still included the same odd characters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this was a quirk with either the PHP version the site was running on or something in the server settings. I tried the code on several other servers with different PHP versions and it worked correctly.

The server setup I was using where the unexpected output occurred was using PHP v5.5.24 and Apache v2.4.12. The localhost server was run on [DesktopServer](http://serverpress.com) version 3.8.3.

I haven't been able to identify the specific issue that caused this to happen, but when I ran the same code on a different server with PHP 7 it worked as expected. I also tried various other PHP versions on different servers and all worked correctly.

One of the following is probably the issue:

- (Most likely) There is something set in php.ini or some other server setting that is causing the site to execute the function incorrectly. I, unfortunately, haven't figured out exactly what the issue is yet though (will update this answer if I find out).
- (Less likely) PHP 5.5.24 has an issue that doesn't output that function correctly. Although there hasn't been a change to [http_build_query since PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) so if there was an issue it should still be present in PHP 7.